# Handle bad Json property values in Jackson

Tags: java, android, parsing, jackson

I am using Jackson library in my android project

I have a class

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class SomeResponse{

@JsonPropery("wiki")
Wiki wiki;
}
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Wiki{
@JsonProperty("title")
String title;
@JsonProperty("description")
String description;
}
```

parse code

```
String resultFromServer = ....;
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.enable(
                Feature.ACCEPT_EMPTY_STRING_AS_NULL_OBJECT);

Wiki str= mapper.readValue(resultFromServer,Wiki.class);
```

now this code work fine 
the problem sometimes the reponse returns like this

```
{wiki:"\n          "}
```

and sometimes

```
{wiki:"\n"}
```

so parsing fails. i can do this

```
 String resultFromServer = ....; 
if (resultFromServer != null && resultFromServer.contains("\"\\\\n\"")) {
            resultFromServer = resultFromServer.replaceAll("\"\\\\n\"", "\"\"");
        }
```

now this code handles this case     `{wiki:"\n"}`
but the second case is not predictable because the number of spaces after the `"\n`

is there a way to handle this error in the property values to be null object ???

Answer (score 1):

You can replace Strings using regular expressions that replaces specific patterns

You can find in detail [here](http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html)

Answer (score 1):

Which version of Jackson are you using? I have tested my solution using version 2.2.2 . In this version you can add constructor to `Wiki` class which accepts `String` parameter.
Your POJO class should look like this:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
class Wiki {

    public Wiki() {
    }

    public Wiki(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    @JsonProperty("title")
    private String title;

    @JsonProperty("description")
    private String description;

    // getters, setters, toString
}
```

Example usage:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.enable(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_EMPTY_STRING_AS_NULL_OBJECT);

SomeResponse response = mapper.readValue(json, SomeResponse.class);
System.out.println(response);
```

If you do not want to create objects with strange content you can also write custom deserializer for `Wiki` class.

```
class WikiJsonDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Wiki> {

    @Override
    public Wiki deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        JsonToken token = jp.getCurrentToken();
        if (JsonToken.VALUE_STRING == token) {
            return null;
        }

        return jp.readValueAs(Wiki.class);
    }
}
```

You can specify deserializer in this way:

```
@JsonDeserialize(using = WikiJsonDeserializer.class)
@JsonProperty("wiki")
private Wiki wiki;
```

Answer (score 1):

`String.replaceAll` takes a regex, you can easily use that to match any number of spaces:

```
resultFromServer.replaceAll("\"\\s*\\\\n\\s*\"", "\"\"");
```

(`\s` being the sign for space). Also, the `contains` test is not quite necessary, but if you want to keep it, you'd have to replace it with a regexp match in order to test for spaces.

regex match for the string using custom indexof method

```
/**
 * contains with regex
 * 
 * @param pattern
 * @param s
 * @return
 */
public static boolean contains(Pattern pattern, String s) {
    return indexOf(pattern, s) > -1;
}

/**
 * indexOf with regex

 * 
 * @param pattern
 * @param s
 * @return
 */
public static int indexOf(Pattern pattern, String s) {
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
    return matcher.find() ? matcher.start() : -1;
}
```

Comment: +1 ...You are right . I did the same thing except for extra \\s* in the beginning "\"\\s*\\\\n\\s*\"" .any way thank you very much i will accept your answer as the correct one .